# Colors in Terminal while using Conque in MacVim

Tags: macos, vim, osx-snow-leopard, macvim

I am using MacVim (snapshot 64) with the Conque (2.3) plugin for executing Bash on Snow Leopard. I would love to have colors on terminal...

I've tried:

```
let g:ConqueTerm_TERM = 'xterm-256color'
let g:ConqueTerm_Color = 1
```

but it doesn't work. Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Ref:

[http://code.google.com/p/macvim/](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/%20Macvim)

http://code.google.com/p/conque/wiki/Usage

Comment: I think the title of your question doesn't reflect its content.

Comment: @nulltoken sorry about that. It is corrected now.

Comment: I use both and have colored output with no extra settings, have you tried running them with a minimal .vimrc and no other plugins?

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe that Snow Leopard supports 256 colors on the Terminal. Try using [iTerm](http://iterm.sourceforge.net/) instead.